# How to get versioning information of a s3 object?

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I need to get versioning information of objects. Forexample i have an object key and a bucket name and with this information i can get his version id via getObject method. But what i need is to know how many version has that object.

```
getObject(bucketName, key).getObjectMetadata().getVersionId()
```

Forexample this method `listVersions`

```
 public VersionListing listVersions(String bucketName, String prefix) throws SdkClientException, AmazonServiceException {
        return this.listVersions(new ListVersionsRequest(bucketName, prefix, (String)null, (String)null, (String)null, (Integer)null));
    }
```

How should i use here bucket name and key to retrieve versioning information of an object?

Comment: I think this will help - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ListVersionsRequest.html

Comment: @RishikeshDhokare Im already aware of listversioning methods, but i couldn't figure it out how i can get it with only bucket name and key.

Comment: key is the object name right?

Comment: @RishikeshDhokare yes i can get key (object name) and urlDecodedKey both

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the code which i found to get versioning information.

```
ListVersionsRequest request = new ListVersionsRequest()
                            .withBucketName(bucketName)
                            .withPrefix(bucketKey);

VersionListing versionListing = s3Service.listVersions(request);

List<S3VersionSummary> versionSummaries = versionListing.getVersionSummaries();
```